# Check if a link on the page contains a string

Tags: javascript, url, contains

(I'm a complete newbie so please forgive me if this isn't clear!)

Is there a way to check if a URL (on the page, not of the page) contains a certain string, and then open said link? e.g. on a news website, check if a link (article) on the page contains "entertainment" and then open any links that contain that, in order to open all articles related to entertainment.

I've only been able to do it for if the URL of the page I'm on contains xyz, using window.location.href.indexOf, and not for URLs that are on the page.

Comment: You have to select all the hyperlink elements, something like `document.querySelectorAll( 'a' );` and then loop over each of those link elements. Each element will have a `href` attribute that contains the url they will route to. So if you get that url string, by using `.getAttribute('href');` for example, you can then check if it contains the word. If it does, you can use `window.open();` to actually go to that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of doing what you need.  I've added 3 links in HTML and added some Javascript to find the one with the text `stack` in it and click it.

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; i++) {
  var link = links[i];
  if (link.href.indexOf("stack") !== -1) {
    link.click();
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com">google</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">stack overflow</a><br/>
<a href="https://bbc.co.uk">bbc</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6 Style

```
for (let link of document.getElementsByTagName("a")) {
  if (link.href.search("stack") > -1)  link.click();
}
```